# How to parse a german date string with luxon?

Tags: typescript, luxon

I want to parse a german Date "02.03.2023" (Which is the second of March 2023) to a dateTime with luxon. This is my code:

```
const format = 'dd.MM.YYYY';
console.log(format);
const date = DateTime.fromFormat('02.03.2023', format, {
    locale: 'dt-AT',
});
console.log(date);
```

But unfortunally the result is invalid. This is what my console logs:

```
{
  "ts": 1710780576251,
  "_zone": {},
  "loc": {
    "locale": "de-AT",
    "numberingSystem": null,
    "outputCalendar": null,
    "intl": "de-AT",
    "weekdaysCache": {
      "format": {},
      "standalone": {}
    },
    "monthsCache": {
      "format": {},
      "standalone": {}
    },
    "meridiemCache": null,
    "eraCache": {},
    "specifiedLocale": null,
    "fastNumbersCached": null
  },
  "invalid": {
    "reason": "unparsable",
    "explanation": "the input \"02.03.2023\" can't be parsed as format dd.MM.YYYY"
  },
  "weekData": null,
  "c": null,
  "o": null,
  "isLuxonDateTime": true
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is the format token, you should use lowercase `yyyy` for four-digit year instead of `YYYY`, see [Table of tokens](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/parsing?id=table-of-tokens) in the documentation.

Example:

```js
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;
const format = 'dd.MM.yyyy';
console.log(format);
const date = DateTime.fromFormat('02.03.2023', format, {
    locale: 'dt-AT',
});
console.log(date.toISO());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@3.4.4/build/global/luxon.min.js"></script>
```